# Not able to pass the selected value to the main dialog in bot framework V4 C#

Tags: c#, botframework

I have set of adaptive cards which are shown once the bot loads. On action.submit I'm able to get the value of the card selected by the user, but I'm not able to pass that value to the next step in main dialog.

OnTurnAsync following code is written:

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        var activity = turnContext.Activity;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
        {
            activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
        }

        // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        switch (activity.Text)
        {
            case "{\"choice\":1}":
                break;
            case "{\"choice\":2}":
               // var msg = $"Platform Assistance";
               // await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(msg), cancellationToken);
                var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                var response = CreateResponse(turnContext.Activity, welcomeCard);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
                //var response = CreateResponse(turnContext.Activity, welcomeCard);
                break;
        }
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
    }
```

And in Main Dialog

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleResponseAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var userResult = stepContext.Result;              

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"INPUT: {stepContext.Result}");
        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }
```

I expect I should get the choice selected by the user once all the cards are shown, which will be further passes to the LUIS intents

I have tried using the text prompt as well but the code doesnt seems to go into the "HandleResponseAsync" method.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple issues.

#### The main one

You're calling these too early:

```cs
// Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
```

They need to be the very last thing in `OnTurnAsync()`. Move them to the end and the user's response will go through to the next step.

#### Additional

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
```

You have this at the end of `OnTurnAsync()`, which is going to make it look like everything from the bot comes from the user. Just delete it.

#### Resources

We just wrote a blog post about [using Adaptive Cards](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) that you may find useful.

I also wrote an [AdaptiveCardPrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5396) that you could use instead of a Text/Choice Prompt. Getting it to work in C# is a little tricky since some of the classes are `internal`/`protected`. You'd either need to change some of the constants from `Prompt` or fork the [Dotnet SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet). Not recommended. I've also got some [Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1616) that use the AdaptiveCardPrompt. Again, C# has issues. The hope is that this will be in the SDK, soon, but this is still TBD.

Comment: Hi Richardson, I did as you suggested but still it didnt go to the main dialog. Anything else is missing?

Comment: @user64870 Can you share a link to your repo? I used your included code and made the changes above and it worked fine for me. Tough to diagnose further without all of your code.

Comment: Hi
My code location: https://github.com/usheveta/BotV4/blob/master/LuisBot.zip
I have made few changes its not calling the dialogs now. Also when I publish this bot the cards don't show up without user saying hi, but in emulator it works fine. Any idea why so?

Comment: Note to others: OP and I are corresponding via email for the subsequent issues. The answer above solves the posted problem, but there's other issues preventing OP from getting it to work.